# JQGrid true scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

My JqGrid code is as given below

```
$('#grid').jqGrid({
    url: '',
    scroll: 1,
    postData: {
        ...
    },
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: [....],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'source',
        index: 'source',
        width: '100',
        align: 'center',
        stype: 'select',
        searchoptions: {
            dataUrl: 'getSource'
            }
    }, { ...
    }],
    rowNum: 200,
    height: '450px',
    autowidth: false,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    pager: '#table-page',
    sortname: '...',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'asc',
    caption: "Records",
    emptyrecords: "Empty records",
    loadonce: false,
    loadComplete: function() {
       ....
    },
    jsonReader: {
       ....
    }
});
```

When I scroll the grid slowly and reach 200 the grid reloads but the view shows View 1-400 of 2000.

If I keep scrolling slowly then I see View 1-600 of 2000.

We can also see that in demo http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html -> New in 3.7 -> True Scrolling and see the same bug.

Can someone please suggest me a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working as designed ... if you scroll slowly it adds records to the table - so you can scroll up and the data is still present - if you scroll fast the current data is removed and only the new data is added using the number of rows you specify at a starting point matching the scroll position

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I find it a bit strange but reasoning seems valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the numbers if you want, using the `viewrecords` option:

```
viewrecords: false
```

The [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) has more details:

> If true, jqGrid displays the beginning and ending record number in the grid, out of the total number of records in the query. This information is shown in the pager bar (bottom right by default)in this format: “View X to Y out of Z”. If this value is true, there are other parameters that can be adjusted, including emptyrecords and recordtext.

Comment: I consider it as a valid option if users complain about view records. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code: remove old data but keep scroll position:

```
beforeProcessing: function(data, status, xhr){
    // Prevent from loading duplicate data
    var firstId = data.rows[0].id;
    if (-1 != $("#"+firstId ).index()){
        return false;
    }

    // Keep scroll position
    $.scrolltop = $(this).closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollTop();

    // Clear old data -> This will make scroll position to zero
    $(this).jqGrid('clearGridData', true);

    // Show white Div portion
    $(this).parent().children('div').eq(0).show();
},
loadComplete: function (data) {
    // Set height of white Div portion
    $(this).parent().children('div').eq(0).height($.scrolltop);

    // Re-set scroll position
    $(this).closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollTop($.scrolltop);
}
```